# Wordpress Blog first row 2 column Second and continuing rows 3 columns

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs

I would like to create a Wordpress archive blog template using Bootstrap.

The first row should have the first post as 8 columns and the second post as 4 columns.

The 2nd row and continuing rows should have the posts as 4 columns.

I believe a php counter would enable this template. Does someone know how the code should be written?

Example Template:
[image]

Comment: Try it and post your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by getting all the posts with [`get_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) to get your posts, which will return an array of [`WP_Post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) objects. I'd then loop through the posts like so:

```
// Get all our posts, and start the counter
$postNumber = 0;
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 8
);
$posts = get_posts($args);
// Loop through each of our posts
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    // If we're at the first post, or just before a post number that is divisible by three then we start a new row
    if (($postNumber == 0) || (($postNumber+1) % 3 == 0)) {
        echo '<div class="row">';
    }
    // Choose the post class based on what number post we are 
    $postClass = '';
    if ($postNumber == 0) {
        $postClass .= "col-md-8";
    } else {
        $postClass .= "col-md-4";
    }
    echo '<div class="'.$postClass.'">';
    // Print the post data...
    echo $postNumber. " " . $postClass;
    echo "</div>";
    // If we are at the second post, or we're just after a post number divisible by three we are at the end of the row
    if (($postNumber == 1) || (($postNumber-1) % 3 == 0)) {
        echo '</div>'; // close row tag
    }
    $postNumber++; // Increment counter
}
```

This will give you some output like this:

[image: output-data]

You'll obviously need to modify this based on your template but this should give you a nice starting point.

Comment: Thanks James I will implement this

Comment: James templates display perfectly, How do you pull in the data, Title & excerpt?

Comment: If you read the codex page for WP_Post (https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) you can access data like the title using `$post->post_title;`. There's also details on the codex for all the data you can get from a post object and how to properly process some data using `apply_filter`

Comment: Thanks James, Worked perfectly